# Do we need a new tag for the Factor programming language?

Tags: support

The [Factor programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_%28programming_language%29) is an modern language in the spirit of [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29). That is what the ["factor" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/factor/info) describes itself as being about. However, if you look at the [questions *tagged* "factor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factor) most of then seem to be about the mathematical concept of ["factoring"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) rather than the language for which the tag is supposedly for. 
In fact, of the 251 questions tagged "factor", [187 (~75%) are also tagged "r"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factor+r) (ie a math oriented programming language unrelated to "Factor"). Many of [the remaining questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factor+-r) are not about the language either.

Is the right course of action to perhaps relegate the "factor" tag to the mathematical concept (as a synonym of ["factoring"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring) and ["prime-factoring"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prime-factoring)) and create a new tag "factor-language" for what "factor" was intended?

Comment: `factor` is a fundamental datatype in the R programming language.  The tag wiki has never mentioned R, but it is easy to see why someone would tag some R questions with this tag.  This usage is popular for a good reason, and perhaps `factor` should refer to this usage.

Comment: I would say that extremely few questions with the tag are about mathematical factorization.  And some of the questions with the `factor` tag but without the `R` tag are actually about `R` factors.

Comment: Related discussion - [Is \[\*-lang\] an acceptable tag? And \[factor\] discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197827)

Comment: Note that `factor-lang` already exists and has three questions, all about the Factor language.  Are there three Factor questions in the `factor` tag?

Comment: There were 21 questions in the [factor] tag that were actually about the language Factor.  I retagged them all to [factor-lang].  Activity seems to have waned more than two years ago.  I have not suggested an edit on the [factor] tag wiki, nor created a [factor-r] tag.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199861/proper-protocol-for-usurping-updating-tags-to-account-for-meaning-shift

Comment: @BenBolker Quite related.  And in fact, at least one question formerly tagged [factor] was not only closed but deleted as a result of the retagging.  For some reason, I was thinking that [r-factor] would not show up if someone attempted to tag with "factor" but I believe that it will.  Retagging the R questions is more work than changing the tag wiki, but letting [factor] die is probably the best path going forward.

Answer (score 9):

The `R` usage of [factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factor) refers to a fundamental datatype in that language. It is used to store categorical data and has nothing to do with mathematical factorization.

Because `R` users will continue to use [factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factor) if it exists, this tag should refer to the `R` `factor` or it should not exist.  Taking over the tag seems excessive, so instead the tag should not exist.

Thus, it is (now) my opinion that the existing questions about the Factor language should be tagged (with the previously-existing) [factor-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factor-lang), and all questions about `R` factors should be tagged [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor), which reads better than "factor-r".

For questions about mathematical factorization, [factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factorization) is appropriate.

Most of the Factor language and mathematical factor questions have been retagged.  I created [r-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-factor) and gave it some wiki text (thanks, reviewers) and will work through the remaining questions as time permits.  Then we can let [factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factor) die to prevent low-rep `R` users from misusing the tag.

Comment: Well the math usage is usually in relation to code that performs factorization such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17030190/254477). Not usually great questions, but on-topic enough to warrant a tag. Perhaps we need *two* new tags "factor-language" and "r-factor"?

Comment: I wouldn't introduce `factor-language`, just leave it as `factor` (we don't have 'language' after any other language tags. Tags can have multiple meanings, especially when used on conjunction with other tags - it just needs to be clearly described in the wiki.

Comment: @ArtB The R tag might be better written as `factor-r` so it shows up when someone types `factor` into the box.

Comment: @slugster If I were looking for questions to answer about the language factor, I would be pretty annoyed at sharing the tag.

Comment: I just looked at my SO profile.  I have a total score of 23 for 7 answers in the `factor` tag.  Without trying, of course.

Comment: @slugster Not very often, but some language tags do have `-language` suffixes.  `clean-language` `visual-format-language` `idl-programming-language` `http-accept-language`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I don't have enough rep to do anything about this, if you do that maybe you'll know what to do

Comment: @ArtB I wouldn't call the current score on this answer any sort of consensus.  I'm inclined to give it a bit and see what happens.

Comment: We have a similar issue with the language Red.  We keep getting people who tag their questions with red because it involves the color red somehow.  We're toying with changing to red-lang if it gets too annoying.  But it would be nice if some tags could be restricted to reputation above eg. 50 to stop these errors.